# Is it possible to check phone number is already registered in firebase else goto sign up

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

Is there anyway to check entered mobile number in login activity is already registered with firebase before generating OTP? If not registered, I want to goto signup activity.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one solution:

You can write a Cloud function and add each phone number to Cloud Firestore while using Phone Authentication and then you can easily call the function from your app and check whether it is registered or not.

Visit https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable

Comment: can you provide me a example code i'm not familiar with cloud firestore.

Comment: You can also work with Firebase Realtime Database. It's very easy just checkout.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/

Answer (score 0):

There is no API in the Firebase Authentication Android SDK to check if a phone number is already in use. I'm not sure why that is actually, so it might be worth [filing a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/).

The only place such an API currently exists in the Firebase Admin SDK, which is designed to be used in a trusted environment such as a server you control, or Cloud Functions. For more on this API, see the [reference documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.Auth#getUserByPhoneNumber).

You'll have to wrap this call in an endpoint you can call from your Android code. The simplest way to do this right now is with a so-called [Callable Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable). But this is still quite involved, so only go this path if you're comfortable with the technologies used.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I found a solution and i posted it as a answer please check and let me know it will work or not please.

Comment: That's indeed a common alternative. Both approached work, but are quite different. My answer works without storing additional user data, but can only be used from a trusted environment. Your answer works directly from the client, but requires that you write the phone number from that client when the user (first) signs in.